# Ordered Graph Problem

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, dynamic-programming, directed-graphs

Let G = (V, E) be a directed graph with nodes v1, v2, . . . , vn.

We say that G is an ordered graph if it has the following properties.

(i) Each edge g Let G = (V, E) be a directed graph with nodes v1, v2, . . . , vn. We say
that G is an ordered graph if it has the following properties.
(i) Each edge goes from a node with a lower index to a node with a higher index. That is,
every directed edge has the form vi
, vj with i < j.

(ii) Each node except vn has at least one edge leaving it. That is, for every node vi
, i =
1, 2, . . . , n − 1, there is at least one edge of the form (vi
, vj ).
goes from a node with a lower index to a node with a higher index. That is,
every directed edge has the form vi
, vj with i < j.
(ii) Each node except vn has at least one edge leaving it. That is, for every node vi
, i =
1, 2, . . . , n − 1, there is at least one edge of the form (vi
, vj ).

b) ] Give an efficient algorithm using dynamic programming approach that takes an
ordered graph G and returns the length of the longest path that begins at v1 and ends at
vn

For question b) I am not really confident with dynamic programming so this is the algorithm i chose

```
Let M[v(i)] be the length of the longest path for v(1) to v(i).

for i=1 to i=n
   
    assign -∞ to M[v(i)]

M[v(1)]=0

for i=1 to i=n

 if M[v(i)] >= 0 

   for each v' reachable from v(i)

     M[v']=max(M[v(i)] + 1, M[v'])

return(M[v(n)]
```

Is the algorithm correct?
I also can't figure out the running time whether it is O(m) or O(m+n).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: edited the question to be more specific